# A quadratic function is a function of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$, where $a, b$ and $c$ are constants.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given any 3 points in the plane, there is exactly one quadratic function whose graph contains these points.  Find the quadratic function whose graph contains the points $(−5,112), (0,2),$ and $(−2,22)$.

Apparently you have to do like a set of $3$ equations but i am not getting it i tried these types of questions too many times.

Comment: What exactly are you not getting ? Are you unable to form the $3$ equations  or unable to solve the $3$ equations ?

Comment: I just thought I'd note that the wording of the first sentence isn't quite right... a problem arises if two of the points have the same $x$ value.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Just substitute points directly into an equation; you'll find, for example, that

$$a(-5)^2 + b(-5) + c = 112 \implies 25 a - 5b + c = 112$$

Do this twice more to get three equations in three variables. Then solve, starting with the equation corresponding to $(0, 2)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can set them in the equation as
$$112=a(-5)^2+b(-5)+c\iff 112=25a-5b+c$$
$$2=a\cdot 0+b\cdot 0+c\iff 2=c$$
$$22=a(-2)^2+b(-2)+c\iff 22=4a-2b+c$$
Since $c=2,$ setting this in the first and the third equation will give you
$$112=25a-5b+2\iff 25a-5b=110\iff 5a-b=22$$
$$22=4a-2b+2\iff 4a-2b=20\iff 2a-b=10$$

Answer (score 1):

Just write it down:
$$f(x)=112\frac{x(x+2)}{-5(-5+2)}+2\frac{(x+5)(x+2)}{5\cdot2}-22\frac{(x+5)x}{(-2+5)(-2-0)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The function is $f(x)=4x^2-2x+2$

Comment: It should be 4 x^2 - 2 x + 2. Typo, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, Thank you!